# How to remove pigments from white clothes that have been accidentally laundered with strong colors clothes?

Tags: clothing, laundry

Accidentally I've laundered white socks with a red t-shirt. Now I have pink socks. So my question is: How to remove pigments from white clothes that have been accidentally laundered with strong colors clothes?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a tip. If you bought new coloured clothes, wash them once on their own, just add one piece of white fabric ( Old T-Shirt for example, make slice out of it so you have multible pieces of fabric for further tests). This has two effects. 1. Removes possible harmful chemicals like bleach, 2. Shows you how much of colour the garment releases. Sure this lowers with time, but it's an nice indicator.

Answer (score 6):

**If** the clothes can tolerate chlorine bleach, that should be effective, since they were white to start.

Scrubbing small spots with dish-washing detergent and toothbrush works if the color is only a small area.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is to put everything white back through the wash immediately, before the items are dry, preferably on the hottest wash they can take. Having made my partner's cricket whites pale pink in a similar situation, running them back through straight away cleared it, but I have since adopted the use of those Colour Catcher things... I think they also make a colour run corrective for these situations. As its only socks, you might not want to wash those on their own... I'd try soaking in Vanish Oxyaction for 6 hours.

Comment: That Vanish stuff (I use another make) is magic. I can even get the collar of my son's band uniform white again. There are different ways to use it; add to the washing powder, soak in a bucket before washing, or mix to a paste and leave for a while before washing. Read the instructions.

Comment: Yes, its brilliant stuff - even gets red wine stains off a linen tablecloth!